# Shift+Insert key inserts 0 instead doing paste in VNC server

Tags: vnc

While working with linux machines/terminal, I always use shift+Insert to paste the clip board content. I am using vnc viewer app to login to my VNC server but shift+Insert isn't working in the Linux based VNC server. Whenever I try to do shift+Insert, it outputs 0 in the terminal of VNC server. But in other applications(like browser, notepad, putty etc.) in my local PC, shift+Insert works and pastes the clipboard content. Only with VNC, I am hitting this problem. How do I make the shift+Insert to do paste instead of outputting 0 in the VNC server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at these two questions. Your problem might be related to the `Send Primary` setting. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433612/vnc-seems-to-break-clipboard-and-primary and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178003/deleting-text-selection-in-vnc-cuts-it-instead-of-deleting-it

Comment: Both the post and it's answers are more about the way to handle clipboard content related issues. In my case, there is no issue with clip board content. But the problem is with the key combination interpretation of VNC. When other apps of local PC takes the shift+Insert combination as paste operation, VNC outputs zero. I hope this may be because in my laptop 'insert' is available as part of num pad 0 key. Other applications always takes the key as 'insert' along with shift lock. But VNC makes a temporary numlock(with shift lock) and outputs 0.

Comment: Use a different key combination to paste.